# How to deal with annoyingly large tabs in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea, tabs, ide, coding-efficiency

Working with some project I'd really like to keep like 8-10 tabs (=files) open at the same time within IntelliJ IDEA as I have to switch between those very often. However the space on the screen is limited especially if the *Project* Browser and the *Remote Host* Browser are also open at the same time.

Usually its not that much of a problem but as soon as some remote files are open the labels become very long and therefore the space for tabs decreases even more. Look at the following picture:

[image: ntelliJ large tabs problem]

A maximum of four tabs at the same time is visible - sometimes only three.

Its not like others have not found very elegant solutions for this - look at the "pinned tabs" feature of google Chrome for instance:

[image: Chrome pinned tabs]

Is there some setting, extension or other possibility how to deal with this problem in IntelliJ? After some research I have only found out that you can switch recent files with `Ctrl + E` but in my opinion this still is a quite clumsy way to deal with it (especially as it does not work for remote files)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can play with `Preferences | Editor | General | Editor Tabs` settings. For example, if you untick `Show tabs in one row`, your extra tabs will be placed in several lines. Also you can untick `Show file extension` and `Show directory for non-unique file names` options.

Comment: Thanks this helps a bit especially the multiline tabs. Not perfect because I would prefer to simply shorten the labels but it looks like that I will have create a feature request in the intellij bug tracker for this wish.